# How to disable the remainder of a circuit when a charger is plugged in, using minimal components?

Tags: transistors, batteries, battery-charging, circuit-design

Is it possible to detect if a charger in plugged in, and disable (or completely disconnect) any of the remaining circuit?
[image: an image of a thing]

This image from [Detecting When a USB Device Is Plugged In For Status LED](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/212078/detecting-when-a-usb-device-is-plugged-in-for-status-led) provides an interesting idea to light up an LED when it is charging, but it uses way too many components for my use case.

I'm using a LiPo battery attached to a microUSB charging circuit. Assume that the non-battery circuit consist of a single op-amp. How would I disconnect or lower the power voltage beneath usability for the op-amp when the circuit is plugged in, without draining the actual battery charging part of the circuit?

Is the only option to use a mechanical switch?

Comment: Yeah, the only option is to use a mechanical switch. There has been absolutely zero technological development since [1907](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor).

Comment: So far, I have read your question 3 times. I don't quite understand your setup. Can you draw a diagram or picture of some kind? Do you basically just want to turn off the op-amp when 5V is present? That is pretty easy, but we would need to see what else is connected to the op-amp.

Comment: I hope you do not neglect the safety of overcharging current or voltage in your attempt to simplify the design.

Comment: BTW what purpose is R4 ?and does CMP1 work at the 5V rail input? and where is your OCP?